# fopen('filename', 'w') returns false but file_exists('filename') returns true

Tags: php

Need help

```
$file = fopen('data.json', 'w');
var_dump($file);
```

The output of this is `bool(false)`

But when I do this

```
var_dump(file_exists('data.json'));
```

The output is `bool(true)`.

What might be the problem?

I've tested it yesterday and it's working fine. But now it won't. I uploaded it to hosting and it still works fine.

I've tried changing the filename to something that doesn't exist for fopen() to create the file. But it doesn't.

**TEMP FIX:**
Not totally fixed because giving 777 permission to file isn't the real fix i guess. I'm still thinking why fopen() works fine yesterday without full permission and with the same user.

Comment: maybe you don't have write permission to the file

Comment: ```ls -la data.json``` says -rw-rw-r-- 1. Should I change it to rw-rw-rw?

Comment: if the process running php is not owned by your user then you can either change the process owner or change the "others" permission to rw

Comment: Okay. So I changed it to rw-rw-rw and now it's working. But another question. Yesterday the permission is just rw-rw-r but it works fine. What might be the problem?

Comment: PHP was running using a different user, which had write permissions while the one ruinning it now doesn't

Comment: I only have one user.

Comment: How can I change the permission of the running php?

Comment: @Muyie to SOLVED: php fopen permission issue refer link : https://www.linode.com/community/questions/7217/solved-php-fopen-permission-issue

Comment: Still didn't fix the problem. But I've learned something there. fopen('filename', 'w') will create the file if it doesn't exist. I've tried it on my code, and it failed to create the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your permission to the directory that contains the file. You see when file don't exist it will still create the file. See php fopen documentation. Here's the link: [fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Comment: woah the question has been answer?

Comment: Yes. When I changed the filename to something that doesn't exist, it doesn't create new file. So maybe the problem is the php running?

Comment: Then it must be your permission to the directory. Are you running it to a linux machine?

Comment: Try chmod -R 777 /var/www    This will give all permission to the user, if this works try to lower the permission to your desired permission level

Comment: Yes. I'm new to linux so I don't have much knowledge to managing files and folders. What should I check permission then? The whole /var/www? or just the folder inside it

Comment: That did the trick. Got it working. I'm thinking why fopen() is working fine yesterday without full permission, and with the same user. Btw, thanks